# Journals of applied mathematics with an economics bent?

Tags: soft-question, journals, applications, economics

I'm asking here instead of the economics stackexchange because I'm interested more in the applied mathematics part, instead of just the economics; I'm interested in seeing what new research is being published, and what are the ongoing trends and currents in this area. In that sense, would anyone have interesting journal suggestions for someone interested in applied mathematics, but with a touch of economics, or applied mathematics aimed at economics?

(cross-posted here from MSE given the lack of answers)

Comment: Something like this: https://www.springer.com/series/4129/books ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.resurchify.com/impact/category/Applied-Mathematics

Journal of Econometrics is a journal covering the categories related to Applied Mathematics (Q1); Economics and Econometrics (Q1); History and Philosophy of Science (Q1). It is published by Elsevier BV. The overall rank of Journal of Econometrics is 462. ISSN of this journal is/are 3044076.